# How To get Ripple effect like play store on tab click with changing color of toolbar and notification bar?

Tags: android

I am new in android.i am trying to achive ripple effect on tab click with color chages of toolbar and notification bar like play store.how to do that?Please Help

[image]

Comment: do you already have a solution for the toolbar and notification background colors change?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get ripple effect on devices of Android 5.0,new drawable `ripple_bg_drawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="#d10c1d" <!--ripple color-->
    tools:targetApi="LOLLIPOP">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#8cc476" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

then add `android:background="@drawable/ripple_bg_drawable"` to your widget

or like this:

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

you should add this code to your layout file!,but this way you can't customize the ripple color!

but if you want to be compatible with devices below Android 5.0,the only way is you do it yourself by customizing! 
Here is a open source project [RippleView](https://github.com/siriscac/RippleView)

Answer (score 0):

There is a library that helps you achieve that:
https://github.com/armcha/PlayTabLayout

```
<io.armcha.playtablayout.core.PlayTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/playTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="some_dp" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Create `res/drawable/ripple_effect.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="#af0c0e"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#af0c0e" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Then create `res/layout/ripple_animation.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:elevation="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Ripple Animation/Effect in Android" />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:elevation="6dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Ripple Animation/Effect in Android" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:elevation="6dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
           android:text="Ripple Animation/Effect in TextView" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:elevation="6dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Ripple Animation/Effect in TextView" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Try this example. For set ripple effect use `android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"`.

Answer (score -4):

set below properties to the view on which you need ripple effect.

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: The user clearly needs a combine ripple effect on both app bar and tabs like on google playstore tabs.